# How to select second columns' data referring to the first column?

Tags: mysql, sql

If we have a 8x2 table where the first column has the row names and the second column has the input data, how do we select the data from the second column ?
Consider the following table(or rather a form) :

1. Name            __________
2. Class           __________
3. Roll Number     __________
4. School          __________
5. Address         __________
6. Contact Number  __________
7. Father's Name   __________
8. Mother's Name   __________

Comment: Could you add some example and your expecting result?

Comment: Got to do better than that! And mothers and fathers? How quaint!

Comment: From your question, I think you are confused about how to use table.
Things you are trying to achieve aren't that hard when you are using SQL.
Refer [here](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-select-statement.htm), you will get a basic idea how SQL works.
If I'm wrong about your confusion, please let me know, I'll try to help you :)

Comment: @Strawberry This was just an example. I am actually not working on something like this. :)

Comment: @Drag0nKn1ght- The link you referred was quite helpful.
But I am still not sure of how to select the data from the second column, which has no name and has just the inputs given by the user.

Answer (score 2):

Your table structure is wrong.
It shoud be like this 
CREATE TABLE INFO(Name varchar(20),class int....etc);

The use queries like,
select Name from INFO where class=8;

Answer (score 0):

For your form Table structure you want fallow is no good.Better take table structure as

***Name  Class Roll Number School Address ContactNumber FatherName MotherName***

and then you can query whatever the column you want.

```
select column from table where name='name'
```

Please let me know if you need any clarification